# r element frequency and column name

Tags: r, frequency, ranking, frequency-distribution

I have a dataframe that has four columns A, B, C and D:

```
A    B    C    D
a    a    b    c
b    c    x    e
c    d    y    a
d              z
e
f
```

I would like to get the frequency of all elements and lists of columns they appear, ordered by the frequency ranking. The output would be something like this:

```
  Ranking  frequency column 
a    1         3      A, B, D
c    1         3      A, B, D
b    2         2      A, C
d    2         2      A, B
e    2         2      A, D
f  .....
```

I would appreciate any help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please post the dataframe with `dput(dfrm)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='A    B    C    D
a    a    b    c
b    c    x    e
c    d    y    a
d   NA    NA     z
e  NA NA NA
f NA NA NA',stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**Solution**

```
#find unique elements
elements <- unique(unlist(sapply(df, unique)))

#use a lapply to find the info you need
df2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,
        lapply(elements, function(x) {
          #find the rows and columns of the elements
          a <- which(df == x, arr.ind=TRUE)
          #find column names of the elements found
          b <- names(df[a[,2]])
          #find frequency
          c <- nrow(a)
          #produce output
          c(x, c, paste(b, collapse=','))
})))

#remove NAs
df2 <- na.omit(df2)
#change column names
colnames(df2) <- c('element','frequency', 'columns')
#order according to frequency
df2 <- df2[order(df2$frequency, decreasing=TRUE),]
#create the ranking column
df2$ranking <- as.numeric(factor(df2$frequency,levels=unique(df2$frequency)))
```

Output:

```
> df2
   element frequency columns ranking
1        a         3   A,B,D       1
3        c         3   A,B,D       1
2        b         2     A,C       2
4        d         2     A,B       2
5        e         2     A,D       2
6        f         1       A       3
8        x         1       C       3
9        y         1       C       3
10       z         1       D       3
```

And if you want the elements column to be as row.names and the ranking column to be first you can also do:

```
row.names(df2) <- df2$element
df2$element <- NULL
df2 <- df2[c('ranking','frequency','columns')]
```

Output:

```
 > df2
  ranking frequency columns
a       1         3   A,B,D
c       1         3   A,B,D
b       2         2     A,C
d       2         2     A,B
e       2         2     A,D
f       3         1       A
x       3         1       C
y       3         1       C
z       3         1       D
```

Comment: Cannot use "plus one" anymore but that was my upvote.  Did not succeed in my working test case but maybe it will on the questioners' structure.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks Bonded. I had a small bug that didn't include the names of columns for frequency equal to one (fixed now) and also included my the test data as I used it to achieve my outputs.

Comment: So that must be why I saw this strange item? `8 B,B.1,B.2,C,C.1,C.2,D,D.1`, nope still there. I was using `""` for the empty space. Which was why I asked for a dput version.

Comment: @BondedDust Maybe yes. I don't know which test case you used, but it should be fixed now.

Comment: If you use "" as an item it gets counted as a unique "element".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using "dplyr" and "tidyr":

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(var, val, everything()) %>%             ## Make a long dataset
  na.omit %>%                                    ## We don't need the NA values
  group_by(val) %>%                              ## All calculations grouped by val
  summarise(column = toString(var),              ## This collapses
            freq = n()) %>%                      ## This counts
  mutate(ranking = dense_rank(desc(freq))) %>%   ## This ranks
  arrange(ranking)                               ## This sorts
# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# 
#   val  column freq ranking
# 1   a A, B, D    3       1
# 2   c A, B, D    3       1
# 3   b    A, C    2       2
# 4   d    A, B    2       2
# 5   e    A, D    2       2
# 6   f       A    1       3
# 7   x       C    1       3
# 8   y       C    1       3
# 9   z       D    1       3
```